# Transfer table row data to html form page in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

Using Angular JS I am trying to pass the data in a table row that is populated dynamically to an html page. The page would then use that object
that is passed to populate form data.

My html looks like below:

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" name="empRegForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" type="text" ng-model="employee.employeeId" />
    <fieldset class="table-striped">
        <input placeholder="Employee Project Id" type="text" ng-model="employee.projectId" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Employee Name" type="text" ng-model="employee.employeeName" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Method that I have created on the controller is as follows:

```
$scope.updateEmployee = function(employee) {
    var response = $http.put('localhost:8080/employeeManagement/employee', employee);
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = data;
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    });
};
```

EmployeeList html table appears as below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in result.listOfEntities">
    <td>{{employee.employeeId}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)"> <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to redirect the page to the Update html page that contains the form when this button on the  row is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the "track by $index" in your ng-repeat to access to the right employee and send it in your function.
`<ng-repeat="employee in ... track by $index"> <ng-click="update($index)">`

Comment: @HugoTor I guess passing the employee object to the updateEmployee() method would work just fine.

Comment: You're right. Then you want to redirect after the click on your `<a>` ?

Comment: yes to a new html page along with this employee

Comment: Tried using `$location.path` at the end of your function ?

Comment: no. can you elaborate pls

Comment: It allows you to redirect to change the path : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 0):

Added ng-include to load different html page in your table page itself and to toggle it on need basis as like example below,

**In controller:**

```
$scope.loadEmployee = function(employee){
    $scope.employee=employee;
    $scope.employee.visible=true;
};

$scope.updateEmployee = function(employee) {
    var response = $http.put('localhost:8080/employeeManagement/employee', employee);
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = data;
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    });
    $scope.employee.visible=false;
};
```

**In Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in result.listOfEntities">
    <td>{{employee.employeeId}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="loadEmployee(employee)"> <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
</tr>

<div ng-include src="'/employee-update.html'" ng-controller="employeeController" ng-show="employee.visible"></div>
```

**employee-update.html:**

```
<form data-ng-submit="updateEmployee()" name="empRegForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" type="text" ng-model="employee.employeeId" />
    <fieldset class="table-striped">
        <input placeholder="Employee Project Id" type="text" ng-model="employee.projectId" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Employee Name" type="text" ng-model="employee.employeeName" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: where does it specify that the data(employee) needs to be moved a separate html page (UpdateEmployee.html). It is just hitting a rest service

Comment: Yes still it is a same html file,you need $scope.employee to populate the update form right?

Comment: yes but how will clicking a button in my list table redirect me to the update employee page

Comment: Is your Update form is in separate HTML to get redirected. As per my understanding it is in same HTML file. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes it's in a separate html file and i want to take the employee data to that separate html file in the same path

Comment: Then use ng-include in your template and enable/disable it when you need it by ng-show and ng-hide. I've update my answer Please check and let me know.

Comment: suggest can you suggest the required code changes pls

Comment: it's showing this error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: It seems this issue because of your API, Please try to test it with some sample JSON and let me know.

Comment: no, all other apis work absolutely fine. I have cors configured properly in my backend app. it appears there's some problem in moving to that page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142288/discussion-between-salman-kazmi-and-immanuel-kirubaharan-s).